# How to use a variable for Server Path in vNext Build?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Am I using the wrong format?

[Screenshot for my variable setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaBRT.png)

I have tried using `""`, `[]`,`()`, always can't run the build. When I remove the server path, everything works well. Guess I'm using the wrong format for the variable.

Comment: What's the detail version of your TFS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a variable for Server Path for repository is **not support** since TFS2015update2.

> Until TFS 2015 update 1, it was possible to define and use a variable,
>   for Server Path. We have removed the support for this configuration
>   starting update 2, as we have seen cases where this could **lead to
>   severe workspace corruption issues.**
>
> [Source Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/08/01/vnext-build-using-a-variable-for-server-path-for-repository-is-not-supported/)

Comment: Why this is not mentioned in tfs build variable link https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables? Thanks any way.